# setAdapter(T) cannot be applied to (android.widget.ListAdapter) when using fragment

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error at autoCompleteTextView it says `setAdapter(T) cannot be applied to (android.widget.ListAdapter)`

```
public class HomeFragmnet extends Fragment {

    TextInputLayout textInputLayout;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstancesState){
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

        textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.menu_dropdown);
        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drop_items);
        String [] items={"Pune", "Mumbai", "Nashik"};

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() , R.layout.items_list, items );
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter( listAdapter );


        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs of `AutocompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) its `setAdapter` method takes a `<T extends ListAdapter & Filterable>`, meaning the adapter must both extend `ListAdapter` and implement `Filterable`.

`ListAdapter` itself does not implement `Filterable`, but some subclasses such as [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) do.